# correct way of writing form data inside php tag

Tags: php, mysql

what i hoped to achieve is to echo each data as they come out from sql with checkboxes by theur side but it just ignores the form data inside the php

```
<form action = "index.php" method = "post">
<input type = "checkbox" name = "kona"/>
<?php
echo  $selcat . "<br>";

if (isset ( $price_data )) {
    $price_query = "SELECT * FROM titem WHERE comment = '$price_data'";
    $price_result = mysql_query ( $price_query, $connection );
    if (! $price_result) {
        echo 'no' . mysql_error ();
    }
    while ( $price_row = mysql_fetch_array ( $price_result ) ) {

        echo  "<h3>" .  $price_row['item'] . "</h3><br>";
            echo "<input type = checkbox name = selitem" . $selitem . "/><br>";
        echo 'Price = ';
        if (is_numeric ( $price_row ['price'] )) {
            echo $price_row ['price'] . " naira" . "<br>";
        } else {
            echo $price_row ['price'] . "<br>";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo '';
}
?>          
</form>
```

Any ideas as to how i can make this work?

Comment: You can't put a h3 tag inside an input tag.

Comment: I'd consider starting with HTML basics, and also rephrasing the question so that it makes sense. Sidenote: your checking for the existance of $price_data, but I can't see it in the code?

Comment: echo  "<input type = 'checkbox' name = 'selitem'>" echo "<label for='selitem'><h3>" . $price_row['item'] . "</h3></label><br />"

Comment: Oh...ok. I just tried it with the $selitem and still the same. Will edit question now

Comment: You can visit check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38473788/i-want-to-write-forms-like-this-is-this-the-correct-way-to-approach/38474255#38474255

Comment: You can visit check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38473788/i-want-to-write-forms-like-this-is-this-the-correct-way-to-approach/38474255#38474255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're outputting two tags mixed up together, like this:

```
<input type =checkbox name =selitem<h3>...</h3><br> />
```

Perhaps you meant to do:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="selitem" /><h3>' . $price_row['item'] . '</h3><br />';
```

This would output:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selitem" /><h3>...</h3><br />
```

Comment: i just tried that and it still diddnt work out. Just outputted the code without the form data in the php tags

Comment: it wasnt working before because zend framework changed my workspace to its default for reasons unknown to me. Everything seems to be in order now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you concat 2 strings without PHP varaibles between that?

```
echo  "<input type =" . "checkbox" . " name =" . "selitem" . "<h3>" .  $price_row['item'] . "</h3><br>" . "/>";
```

It should be:

```
echo  "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"selitem\"<h3>. $price_row['item']. "</h3><br> />";
```

You have to use array for name:

```
echo  "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"selitem[]\"<h3>. $price_row['item']. "</h3><br> />";
```

And in PHP you can loop foreach on $_POST['selitem'] array - each element is checked element.

Comment: i edited the question with regards to the suggestions given and it still gave me the same thing. I used the concatenations like that because i tried it once before with the <select><option> tags and it worked