# i want to write forms like this is this the correct way to approach..?

Tags: php

```html
search form
<form action="category.php?type=search" method="post">
select all delete form  
<form name="frmMain" method="post">

</form>
</form>
```

Comment: Is there any code you could share?

Comment: `form` inside a `form` is an invalid markup.

Comment: you can use two form on different place  on page.. not form inside form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using to send form using php then below is right way:

```
 //search form
    <form action="category.php?type=search" method="post">

    </form>

//select all delete form  

    <form name="frmMain" method="post">

    </form>
```

if you want to send form using ajax and jquery then you can use this way:

```
//search form
<form action="category.php?type=search" method="post">

  //select all delete form  
   <form name="frmMain" method="post">

  </form>
</form>
```

Example of HTML:5 new form element (from an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21900324) by [ilevent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390440/ilevent)):

> ```
> <form id="saveForm" action="/post/dispatch/save" method="post"></form>
> <form id="deleteForm" action="/post/dispatch/delete" method="post"></form>
>
> <div id="toolbar">
>  <input type="text" name="foo" form="saveForm" />
>  <input type="hidden" value="some_id" form="deleteForm" />
>  <input type="text" name="foo2" id="foo2" form="saveForm" value="success" />
>
>     <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" form="saveForm" onclick="alert(document.getElementById('deleteForm').elements.length + ' ' + document.getElementById('saveForm').elements.length + ' ' + document.getElementById('saveForm').elements['foo2'].value);return false;" />
>     <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" form="deleteForm" />
>     <a href="/home/index">Cancel</a>
> </div>
> ```